# Circular linked list in C

Tags: c

How to delete all the nodes in singly circular linked list? Is this code the right one ? I don't get the output in codeblocks when I tried for it. What is the mistake?

```
void deleteall()
{

    struct node *temp1=head,*temp2;
    do
    {

        while(temp1->next!=head)
        {

            temp1=temp1->next;
        }
        temp2=head;
        head=head->next;
        temp1->next=head;
        free(temp2);
    }while(temp1!=head);
    head=NULL;
    free(temp1);
    printf("deleted successfully\n");
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To delete a singly circular linked list, start from the `next` of `head` and keep on deleting until you reach to `head` and then delete `head` of the list, like this:

```
struct node *temp1 = head->next, *temp2;

while (temp1 != head) {
    temp2 = temp1->next;
    free(temp1);
    temp1 = temp2;
}

free (head);
head = NULL;
```